# I am having problems with wireless

Tags: wireless

First time installing Ubuntu and have windows xp professional as well on my Dell laptop.
I can access the internet through my router with a wire but do not know how to fill the blanks on the wireless part, I know the name of the ssi and password.

Comment: please be a bit more specific. can you describe about which fields you have problems with. Normally you can just click the network, enter a password and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

*Ctrl+Alt+T* to open a terminal.

Issue the command

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
Press Y and Enter when prompted

once the operation completes, restart and see if you can connect to a wireless connection via  your network manager

**The long and dandy of it:**

You're running a Dell, which I assumed is an older one (since you didn't specify) and I am assuming it has a Broadcom wireless chip which requires proprietary drivers, this command will install those.

## if your problem persists

Issue the command

`sudo apt-get remove firmware-b43-installer`
Press Y and Enter when prompted

then issue the command

`lshw -C network`

and post the results in an edit to your question